# FATAL: database "pgdb" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to execute the command

```
psql -d pgdb -U nikiesh
```

It gives below error:

> FATAL:  database "pgdb" does not exist

Comment: Does the database `pgdb` exists?

Comment: What's unclear about the error?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score -1):

It means that the database "pgdb" does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

psql -l | grep pgdb

use this if you are unsure of the whole name of the db. If your using linux.